# Which Arrested Development character was in Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, behind-the-scenes, avengers-infinity-war

While casually waiting through the entire end credits of *Avengers: Infinity War* at 3am to see if there was stinger scene, I noticed that they included thanks to 20th Century Fox for the use of a character from Arrested Development.

While there was a lot going on in the movie, I feel like I would have noticed Gob or Buster in there, yet I didn’t. Which Arrested Development character was used in *Infinity War*, and where?

Comment: Related: [Who was the Arrested Development Character in Avengers: Infinity War?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88429/49)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Radio Times](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/film/2018-04-18/avengers-infinity-war-directors-confirm-hidden-arrested-development-easter-egg/) concludes it was Tobias:

> In the unfinished footage, fans were treated to a scene set in the home of Benicio del Toro’s Collector, the outer-space character from Thor: The Dark World and Guardians of the Galaxy who spends his time gathering rare species and objects.
>
> In the course of this collecting, we previously saw him get his hands on the Reality stone, which is why he factors into the new film – but eagle-eyed viewers also spotted that one of his specimens in the footage looked an awful lot like an Arrested Development character, specifically David Cross’ never-nude analyst/therapist Tobias Fünke in scenes where he painted himself blue while wearing jean-shorts.
>
> Look, he was trying to join the Blue Man Group, and…it makes sense if you watch the series, OK?
>
> Anyway, the Russos’ comments seem to confirm that this bespectacled blue specimen is an intentional callback to the comedy series (which they previously acknowledged in Captain America: Civil War by including the Bluth’s stair car in the background of a scene), and therefore the first official Easter Egg that we can all bask in the glow of before we see all the rest in cinemas next week.

Comment: I can confirm that while not all of that leaked footage made it into the final cut of the film, the shot with Tobias is indeed present in the theatrical cut—it's just really subtle and unless you know it's there and know where to look, you won't catch it, kind of like the stair-car cameo in *Civil War.*

Comment: Also, I just have to say it's pretty cool how the Russos did this.  Back in *Guardians* Vol. 1, we saw Easter eggs pertaining to James Gunn's past work, and now that we're revisiting the location under the Russo brothers' direction we get to see references to their work too.

Comment: @Bob: word. It’s fairly early on in the Knowhere scene. I don’t see jean shorts, but I do see a blue guy in case that looks like Tobias.