# What’s with the clanks at the end of the credits in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

After [casually waiting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186361/which-arrested-development-character-was-in-infinity-war) through the entire end credits of *Avengers: Endgame* at 3am, I was treated to the sight of

> nothing but the Marvel Studios logo.

However, in the background I heard what sounded like

> six... clanks, for want of a better word. Sounds a bit like a hammer striking metal, or perhaps even a jewel of some sort striking what could conceivably be a gauntlet.

Maybe the theatre’s air conditioning was having a moment, or maybe six hours of *Avengers* double bill action had reduced my mind to a creamy paste.

But on the off-chance this is something knowable or deducible: **what were those sounds?**

Comment: Is Endgame a Mark VII Production? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzuDDx3AypM

Comment: This is purely personal subjection but I took it to be a nod to Stark forging the original Iron Man suit. Similarly to how "I am Iron Man" was reused in homage to the film that started the whole MCU.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about the first part being spoiler taggued... ^^ It is a bit devious, imo ;)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Waiting to see what there is at the end is all part of the fun! I couldn’t rob people of that one last time!

Comment: Related: [What's the metal clinking sound at the end of credits in Avengers: Endgame?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99817/49)

Comment: Just a pointer that there were several articles on that already. Were you looking for a more "credible" answer?

Comment: @Jenayah: “there were several articles on that already” — what, articles about the clanks on the internet? That doesn’t preclude asking a question about it here. And, when I asked, about 8 hours after Endgame came out, I’m guessing there weren’t articles.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Your previous edit *is* likely to offend people, and the use of such a word is entirely unnecessary. Do not add it back.

Comment: @Null “Your previous edit *is* likely to offend people” — *[citation needed]*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The fact that another user considered it profanity that needed to be edited out should have been a sufficient clue for you. No citation is really necessary since someone effectively asked you not to use it by editing your post. Nonetheless, for your edification: that word is [considered by some to be taking God's name in vain](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/54675/14775), which they consider a serious sin and is therefore offensive to them.

Comment: @Null: so as long as one person's offended by a word (or thinks others will be offended), we don't get to use it? People get offended by all sorts of weird stuff (Harry Potter, for example, [is considered by some to promote Satanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_debates_over_the_Harry_Potter_series)). How about “damned”. Can I use “damned”?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite If someone is offended by a word and that word is not essential to the post (as is the case here) then, yes, you should refrain from using it out of respect for your fellow user. [This has been the policy of the SE network for nearly its entire existence.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/299342) Furthermore, per the [Code of Conduct](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/conduct) "we don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on...religion".

Comment: @Null: “that word is not essential to the post (as is the case here)” — pretty essential to the tone, as it goes.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I wondered this myself and I think it is probably referencing Tony creating the Mk I Iron Man suit way back in *Iron Man* from 2008. That is where it all started and this is essentially where it all ends.

> Especially for Tony.

Compare the sounds here, or at least until the *Endgame* video is taken down.

The Russo brothers appear to confirm this is correct in an [interview with USA Today](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/life/entertainthis/2019/04/30/why-avengers-endgame-doesnt-have-end-credits-scene-spoilers/3630412002/).

> There is a little something extra, though, as the final "Endgame" credits roll and that familiar Marvel Studios logo pops up onscreen: In the background, you can hear the clanging of Stark (Robert Downey Jr.) building his first Iron Man armor in the original movie.
>
> Anthony Russo calls it "an echo of the past" rather than a tease to someone else wearing the iconic supersuit at a later date.
>
> "It's really just an homage, sort of a little bookend," Joe Russo says. "It started it and it ends it.

On a related note in the same interview they also give their reasons for not including an end credits scene.

> "It was never in the cards," director Joe Russo tells USA TODAY. "It was called 'Endgame' for a reason. This is it. This is the ending. The book is closed on that chapter of the Marvel universe and a new book will get written."
>
> His brother, director Anthony Russo, adds it was a "great thrill" not having to steer the Marvel ship for where it goes next. "This was the first Marvel movie we've done where we weren't thinking about the future."
>
> In addition to "Endgame," they directed "Captain America: The Winter Soldier," "Captain America: Civil War" and "Avengers: Infinity War," always having a "Where's this going?" mindset, Joe Russo says.
>
> Now, "there's no future," Anthony Russo says. "There will be a future, of course, but it's not our responsibility."

Comment: Excellent work! I'll buy that.

Comment: Disney have confirmed the noise is the soundtrack from tony stark building the very first Ironman suit.

Comment: @RichardC got a link for that? Haven’t seen it myself

Comment: I don’t have a link to the specific Disney quote but it is reported as being confirmed on a number of sites such as

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2019/04/avengers-endgame-end-of-credits-sound-iron-man-armor-hammer-suit/amp

Comment: if it's really that noise, then that may be a little loophole being left open a'la Spock in ST2 "Remember...."

Comment: I wouldn’t read anything into it other then it’s a tribute RDJ started this whole journey.

Comment: I kind of like the theory that it’s [Harley from Iron Man 3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/210879/who-was-the-lone-kid-in-the-line-of-people-at-the-lake-at-the-end-of-avengers-e#comment574594_210881) building his own Iron Man suit.

Comment: Meh. I'm sticking with Russo. I think this version/chapter of the MCU is over. Endgame was literally the END. It's the final "book" in the series. Soon, we'll see Disney marketing the "MCU Collection" on their store, and on Amazon.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan "The Infinity Saga" appears to be the name they're going with

Comment: 4. Why no after credit scene? What's with the clanging sound at the end?

Our goal is to bring a sense of conclusion. Currently, we have no plan to direct more Marvel projects after this...unless a really good idea comes up.
Normally Kevin Feige communicates with directors a lot on the story's direction. But not this one. Kevin left the storytelling entirely to us. We don't think about how MCU goes from here, we only look backward.
The clanging sound is an homage to Iron Man
A quote from a q+a by the Russo’s

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bjjipk/spoilers_russo_brothers_qa_in_washington_dc_april/?depth=1