# Who was the lone kid in the line of people at the lake at the end of Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame* we have

> Tony Stark's funeral.

The camera pans through a line of people from Pepper and Cap to the Guardians all the way up to Captain Marvel on the porch. Before we get to Carol there is one boy on his own on the right. He appeared to have longish hair and I didn't recognise who he was.

Who was this character?

Comment: For a good minute or so I thought “That must be Wanda’s kid brother! It’s Quicksilver!” entirely forgetting that he died in *Age of Ultron*.

Comment: Related: [Who's the random kid standing in the gathering at the end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99633/49)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Harley Keener, portrayed by Ty Simpkins

In a throwback to one of the more niche characters, Ty Simpkins reprises his role from [Iron Man 3](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1300854/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) as Harley Keener. This is evident from the [cast list](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) on IMDb.

[image: Ty Simpkins on the red carpet] [image: Harley Keener with Iron Man suit]

Comment: one theory for the end credit audio stinger is that the hammering heard is from Keener

Comment: I see no reason why I should believe that to be Keener. Or why that should interest me?

Comment: The end credit sound is from iron man (1) the scene where tony forged the very first Ironman suit

Comment: Arguably I wouldn't call him a niche character but a main supporting character in Iron Man 3.

Answer (score 14):

It was Harley, from the *Iron Man 3* movie.

[image: Harley as seen in Iron Man 3]

Comment: This answer may be correct but you could improve it by indicating *why* you know that it's him. At the moment it's just a name and a picture.